# Redirect domain in .htaccess to yii application

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, yii

i need redirect domain in .htaccess in root on server.
My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/yii/projectName/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yii/projectName/$1 [L]
```

Home page application works, but url manager doesn't work, it always redirects to home page.

My urlManager:

```
'urlFormat'=>'path',
'showScriptName'=>false,
'rules'=>array(
...
),
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about webmastering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I found this alternative solution a year ago here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/

**EDIT**:

URL manager settings seems to be OK, but be sure to add these rules AFTER your custom url rules:

```
'rules'=>array(

            // ... add you custom url rules here, if there are any

            // Home page
            '/' => 'info/index', // edit this to your home page controller/action

            // Default patterns for any other controller/actions.
            // These are checked last, if there were no applicable custom rules for a specific URL
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*' => '<controller>/<action>'
),
```

Comment: No one tried to redirect domain in .htaccess root serwer on yii aplication?